# Are Money Transfer services better than Bank transfers?

Tags: foreign-exchange

I was planning on moving a chunk of cash from a foreign currency account I have with my bank to a domestic currency account. Same bank, same business, etc - just different currencies.
My bank (ANZ NZ Ltd) - doesn't charge a transfer fee - but the exchange rate isn't great.
While I was checking the exchange rate on XE.com- I noticed they offer a transfer service, which offers considerably better rates, and would net about $600 more in my account.

Am I missing something obvious - or is this a reasonable way to transfer money?

Comment: One obvious thing to check is whether the money  transfer service allows you to transfer money from your foreign currency account to your domestic currency account _in the same bank_ (and possibly in the same branch too)